# Decrease find duplicate record query execution time

Tags: mysql

I have 3 lac of records. I need to count duplicate records and return all duplicate records (Ex. if example@example.com are 10 times then returns all 10 records with duplicate of 10)

I have created query for that but it takes 15 seconds of time. Any suggestion to decrease time?

```
SELECT g.guest_name, g.email, b.totalCount AS duplicate_guest
FROM guest g 
INNER JOIN (SELECT email, COUNT(Id) AS totalCount FROM guest  GROUP BY email ) b ON g.email = b.email
```

Comment: Pls add the output of the explain and also list the indexes you have in the `guest` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to decrease the data for join condition by adding **having** condition like below query.

**Also make sure that there should be an index on email column to optimize it**

```
SELECT g.guest_name, g.email, b.count as duplicate_guests
FROM guest g 
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT email, COUNT(Id) AS count
     FROM guest  
     GROUP BY email 
     HAVING count(*) > 1
) b ON g.email = b.email
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now it takes 1.3 sec
Very helpfull suggestion **index on email**

Answer (score 0):

Just add `HAVING count(*) > 1` to the inner select

```
SELECT g.guest_name, g.email, b.totalCount AS duplicate_guest
FROM guest g 
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT email, COUNT(Id) AS totalCount 
     FROM guest  
     GROUP BY email 
     HAVING count(*) > 1
) b ON g.email = b.email
```

Comment: Thanks, Now  it takes 5 sec